# Cross distinct column values with other table

Tags: mysql

From the distinct values of 'USER' that have in `PERMISSIONS` table (query_1), I intend to cross information with the query values from the table of `ACCESS_CONTROL` (query_2) to know how long each 'USER' with access permissions has not been loged-in.

I intend to cross query_1 with query_1 through the 'USER' key field.
How it's possible to do?

query_1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`USER`) FROM `PERMISSIONS`;
```

query_2:

```
SELECT 

`USER`, 
MAX(`REGISTRY_DATE`) AS MAX_REGISTRY_DATE, 
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),MAX(`REGISTRY_DATE`)) AS DIFFERENCE_IN_DAYS

FROM `ACCESS_CONTROL` 

WHERE STATUS = 'Access Allowed' 

GROUP BY `USER` ORDER BY DIFFERENCE_IN_DAYS DESC;
```

Expected Results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDXjC.jpg

Comment: Please share table schema, sample data and expected output.

Comment: You can use **JOIN** but as @JitendraYadav says, we would need your tables schema ad sample data to help you

Comment: please check the my expected results: https://imgur.com/a/f5KQXWC

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) .. Images are bad for reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a left join of the 1st query to the 2nd:

```
select
  u.user, 
  coalesce(a.registry_date, 'never') max_registry_date,
  coalesce(a.difference_in_days, 'never') difference_in_days
from (
  select distinct user
  from permissions
) u left join (
  select user, max(registry_date) registry_date, 
  datediff(curdate(), max(registry_date)) difference_in_days
  from access_control 
  where `status` = 'Access Allowed' 
  group by user 
) a on a.user = u.user
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oH7fXMSBWALroRbXY9zhcA/1).
Results:

```
| user     | max_registry_date | difference_in_days |
| -------- | ----------------- | ------------------ |
| john     | 2019-09-06        | 0                  |
| susan    | 2019-09-01        | 5                  |
| mike     | 2019-08-06        | 31                 |
| anderson | never             | never              |
```